# Qgis Web Client change the default EPSG 3857 to 29194 SAD 69 UTM ZONE 24

Tags: qgis-web-client

The Qgis standard Web client's initial installation is EPSG default +3857 like to know how to change EPSG 29194 SAD 69 UTM ZONE 24 because all my projects are in this coordinate system.

What is the procedure and changes should I make?

Comment: @nmtoken in globaloptions.js I changed the line

// EPSG projection code of your QGIS project
var authid = "EPSG:" + 3857;

for

// EPSG projection code of your QGIS project
var authid = "EPSG:" + 29194;

but it did not work. displays a pink screen and does not appear the image layer or my layers. :(

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the GIS stackexchange. Personally I've encountered the same problem and also [asked this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126904/custom-crs-in-qgis-web-client) on this stack, but for the sake of it I'll explain once more.

First of all, you were going in the right direction, changing the line "EPSG:" + 29194;. But after that you have to check your apache\htdocs\site\libs\proj4js\defs folder for an actual CRS definition. As someone recommended in my question you can use http://spatialreference.org/ to find your CRS and then copy the Proj4s definition into your new file (create new file inside the apache\htdocs\site\libs\proj4js\defs). Your file should be EPSG29194.js. I've tried to search for you CRP and I hope its the correct one: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/29194/

After you have your new CRS you should also disable the default maps provided by qgis-webclient, because they are projected by the default CRS therefore when you change it to yours, they can no longer be projected correctly (pink tiles). You can disable them by changing the following lines (in GlobalOptions.js):

```
var enableBingCommercialMaps = false;

var enableGoogleCommercialMaps = false;

var enableOSMMaps = false;
```